# Sum values of each key on multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, sum

I have a haystack that i wanna sum the values of each array separately. This is what i have:

```
Array //ALL THE HAYSTACK
(
    [0] => Array //REPRESENTS MONTH 1
        (
            [0] => Array  //REPRESENTS WEEK 1
                (
                    [week] => 1
                    [user1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [sell] => value
                                    [cost] => value
                                    [gain] => value
                                )
                        )

                    [user2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [sell] => value
                                    [cost] => value
                                    [gain] => value
                                )
                        )

                    [user3] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [sell] => value
                                    [cost] => value
                                    [gain] => value
                                )
                        )
                )
            //... MORE WEEKS

        [1] => Array //REPRESENTS MONTH 2
        ( //... ALL THE PROCCES ABOVE
)
```

I'm trying use `foreach()` for every month and for every week, like this:

```
$result = $array('sell' => 0, 'cost' => 0, 'gain' => 0);
foreach ($monthArray as $theMonth => $week){
    foreach ($week as $user){
        $result['sell'] +=  $user['user1'][0]['sell'];
        $result['sell'] +=  $user['user2'][0]['sell'];
        $result['sell'] +=  $user['user3'][0]['sell'];

        //...
```

But, when i print `$result` him SUM EVERY MONTHS, not the specific month that i want...

I want sum every week, and every month. How can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?: The result (`$sales`) is an array. The keys of this array are the months, the values of the array are the totals. The total is gained by iterating over the weeks in the month, and then iterating over the users per week. The latter iteration I introduced myself, because you were using this hardcoded list of user1, user2, user3....

Instead of storing it in another array you could also echo or use it right away, but I think having it in an array is more convenient for further processing. It untangles your code a bit.

```
$result = $array('sell' => 0, 'cost' => 0, 'gain' => 0);
foreach ($monthArray as $theMonth => $week){
    $sales[$theMonth] = 0;
    foreach ($week as $users){
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $sales[$theMonth] +=  $user[0]['sell'];
        }
    }
}

result['sell'] = $sales;
print_r(result['sell']);
```

If you want to have cost and gain per month too, maybe it makes more sense to create an array in the format `$result[month]['sell']` than `$result['sell'][month]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [**array_reduce()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) and [**array_column()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php). An example: here:

```
//$array = your array
$sum_arr = array_reduce($array, function($old, $new){
    $arr = array_filter(array_map(function($v){ return is_array($v) ? $v : '';}, array_shift($new)));
    return [
        'sell' => array_sum(array_column($arr, 'sell')) + $old['sell'],
        'cost' => array_sum(array_column($arr, 'cost')) + $old['cost'],
        'gain' => array_sum(array_column($arr, 'gain')) + $old['gain'],
    ];
}, ['sell'=>0, 'cost'=>0, 'gain'=>0]);
```

**Updated:**

Alternative of `array_column()`:

```
$sum_arr = array_reduce($array, function($old, $new){
    $arr = array_filter(array_map(function($v){ return is_array($v) ? $v : '';}, array_shift($new)));
    return [
        'sell' => array_sum(array_map(function($v){return $v['sell'];}, $arr)) + $old['sell'],
        'cost' => array_sum(array_map(function($v){return $v['cost'];}, $arr)) + $old['cost'],
        'gain' => array_sum(array_map(function($v){return $v['gain'];}, $arr)) + $old['gain'],
    ];
}, ['sell'=>0, 'cost'=>0, 'gain'=>0]);
```

Comment: no need to use loop. Only this code is enough for your `$array`

Comment: but my server php is PHP 5.3... not works `array_columm()` :(